# Json adds \ charcter while returning json format

Tags: asp.net, json

I am creating an API/web service which needs to return JSON format.
I also need to create the web service as a POST request
Sample code below, see more snippets of the source code in the end of this post.

```
Meta meta = new Meta(); 
meta.recipes = new List<Recipe>(); 
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
string strJSON = js.Serialize(meta); 
return strJSON;
```

Problem:
When I try the response in a few REST consoles (list of consoles tried) and in the ASP.NET client, I get this format with an extra "d" and extra \ before each ". See return output below:

```
{"d":"{\"count\":\"0\",\"status\":\"500\",\"recipes\":[]}"}
```

When I try to remove serialization then I get the following format:

```
<Meta xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; xmlns="tempuri.org/">; <count>1</count> <status>200</status> <recipes> <Recipe> <recipeID>1</recipeID> <recipeName>Apple Pie</recipeName> <imageURL>service/it.jpg</imageURL> <rating/> </Recipe> </recipes> </Meta>
```

But I want it in the following format:

```
{"count":"0","status":"500","recipes":[]}

[WebMethod(Description = "Return all Recipe...")] 
[ScriptMethod( ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public Meta RecipeList(string ingredientId, string cuisineId, string dishTypeId, string courseId)
```

This still returns XML even though I return meta object and don't add serialization

Questions:

1. I thought the correct JSON format should be WITHOUT this "d" and the . Is this true or is the correct JSON format of the output actually WITH the "d" and the \?
2. If it should be without, then where do you suggest the correction should be made, on the server side or in the client side?
3. How should I correct this on the server side?
4. How can this be corrected on the client side?

   ```
   [WebMethod(Description = "Return all Recipe...")]
   [ScriptMethod( ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
   public string RecipeList(string ingredientId, string cuisineId, string dishTypeId, string courseId,
           string occasionId, string considerationId, string recipeType, string readyTime, string favouritebyUserId, string bookmarkbyUserId)
   {
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       int rTime = 0;
       if (readyTime == "") rTime = 0;
       else rTime = Convert.ToInt32(readyTime);
       ds = RecipeBLL.SearchRecipe(ingredientId, cuisineId, dishTypeId, courseId, occasionId, considerationId, recipeType, rTime);
       // Create a multidimensional jagged array
       string[][] JaggedArray = new string[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count][];
       int i = 0;    

       Meta meta = new Meta();

       int count = 0;
       meta.recipes = new List<Recipe>();
       foreach (DataRow rs in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
       {
           Recipe recipe = new Recipe {
               recipeID = rs["RecipeId"].ToString(),
               recipeName = rs["RecipeTitle"].ToString(),
                imageURL = rs["Photo"].ToString(),
               rating  = rs["Rating"].ToString()
           };
           meta.recipes.Add(recipe);
           //mlist.Add(recipe);
           count++;
       }

       if (count != 0)
           meta.status = "200";
       else
           meta.status = "500";
       meta.count = count.ToString();
       JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       string strJSON1 = js.Serialize(meta);
       return strJSON1;
   }
   ```

Comment: Is this really the data that is generated or is this just the output in some console or log file? `d` comes from your data structure, which we don't know anything about.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is that *you're* returning a string from your code somewhere - and then it's being encoded as JSON by something else. So the string you're returning is:

```
{"count":"0","status":"500","recipes":[]}
```

... but whatever you're returning from thinks you're *trying* to return a string, rather than an object with a count etc.

You haven't shown any of your code, but I suspect the answer will be to just remove one explicit serialization call.

Comment: If I remove serialization then I get following format: 

<Meta xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<count>1</count>
<status>200</status>
<recipes>
<Recipe>
<recipeID>1</recipeID>
<recipeName>Apple Pie</recipeName>
<imageURL>service/it.jpg</imageURL>
<rating/>
</Recipe>
</recipes>
</Meta>

But I want in the following format:

{"count":"0","status":"500","recipes":[]}

In that case what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample code: Meta meta = new Meta();
 meta.recipes = new List<Recipe>();
 JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string strJSON = js.Serialize(meta);
        return strJSON;

Comment: @user1928185: Please edit the code (including the method declaration) into your question. It sounds like you just need to change your method declaration to include an attribute saying you want it to be serialized as JSON rather than XML.

Comment: @user1928185: Again, you should be editing this into your **question**. Given that, I'd be surprised to see it come back in XML... what are you using to fetch it?

Comment: RestConsole and also asp.net client

Comment: @user1928185: Hang on - with the current method declaration you *couldn't* have returned `meta` without serializing it, as it's declared to return `string`. Change it to return `object`, and then just return `meta`.

Comment: Yah,I removed serialization but it returns xml response.

Comment: @user1928185: Well as I said, the method declaration you gave wouldn't have even compiled without changing the method signature. You still haven't edited your question with any of the information you included in the comments, either. I'm afraid I can't help you without more accurate information.

Comment: WebMethod(Description = "Return all Recipe...")] [ScriptMethod( ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] public Meta RecipeList(string ingredientId, string cuisineId, string dishTypeId, string courseId). It returns xml. I don't add serialization. I return meta object. Can you please give me an answer. Is it possible to return JSON format without serialization? Note: I need json format.

Comment: @user1928185: I would have *expected* that to be fine. Now as I've said *several* times now, put all this information into your *question* instead of into *comments*. Maybe someone else will see what's wrong - I personally suspect it's your diagnostics, but maybe someone else will spot something.